# Crazy Hand WSOP

Tags: betting-strategy, poker-strategy

tournament in the money
sb 30 bb 60 ante 10
like 7 handed

---

**Pre**

hero sb deep has villain covered
K⋄ K♠
bet 160 to go

villain bb deep
Q♣ T⋄
call 160

pot 370

---

**Flop**

A♥ 7♠ 5♥

hero
bet 150

villain
call 150

pot
670

---

**Turn**

J♣

hero
check

villain
bet 370

hero
call 370

pot
1410

---

**River**

K♣

hero
bet 800

villain
raise to 2940 all in

pot
5150

hero
to call 2140

What do you think of how the hand was played?
Would you call?

spoiler (you can easily find it on the Internet)

> hero found a fold

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Uh, would you call?

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-flop:**

Hero should 3x with his entire range. Blind versus blind he will be betting a lot of marginal hands to pick up the blinds and antes. He is playing deepstacked out of position. Don't encourage calls and play balanced in this spot.

**Flop:**

I like hero's sizing. Villain should not call in this spot.

**Turn:**

Hero should have some hands that check here. I feel like he can go either way here. I like betting, because villain can have a lot of weak hands on this board and hero has a range advantage. Hero can also still get some nice value. I like check-calling, because hero does not want to play a huge pot and you give villain a chance to bluff with his draws. I lean more towards betting with kings and checking with some very weak aces, since those hands block villain's value on the turn, but don't block any bluffs.

Once checked to villain should definitely bet turn and river. He doesn't really have showdown value and he does not block potential draws hero could have.

**River:**

Hero should definitely be checking here. If hero donk bets all his good hands, what does his range look like when he checks? Moreover, if villain had a bluff on the turn, you have to let him keep bluffing. If villain has value and bets, you can put him into a tough spot by check-raising all-in. You can balance this out by also check-raising a couple of missed draws. This makes you very difficult to play against.

Once villain shoves hero should snap call. He only loses to aces and QT, both of which are essentially impossible, except for QhTh, but that is only 1 combination. Villain could shove worse and have some bluffs.

Comment: QT hearts should get to the river.

Comment: @paparazzo whoops, you are correct thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Again I not accept my own answer.  I just thought this was an amazing hand.

---

**Pre**

I like the bet by the hero. Don't want to blow the bb off the hand with a big pocket pair. And your bluffs are not as expensive with a moderate raise.  Villain is getting over 2:1 to call an in position.

Good call by villain.  That is the type of hand that if it hits can win a decent size pot if you hit 2 pr or better. And you don't block ace or king. You can get in a spot like happened with a straight versus set.

---

**Flop**

Hero: A weak Ace could be in villains range but KK is probably good here. I like the bet for value.  Could get a call from a weaker pair.

Villain: That is a pretty weak flat.  Queen high is rarely good here.  Two draws he does not have a piece of.  Even if he hits a queen it might not be good.  Ace is in hero's range.  I don't like the call.  QT hearts would be a good call.

---

**Turn**

Hero: I think he is checking to fake weakness.  If villain had JJ should have re-raised pre.

Villain: Picked up a gutter but still likely behind. Was it a bluff?  What hand is going to lay down.  I guess he could represent JJ and fold out 77 or 55.  I would rather see a check back.

---

**River**

OMG could it be any worse for the hero?

Hero: I get the bet and get value from 1 pair or 2 pair.

Villain: No kidding jam.

Hero: How do you get away from this?  You are only losing to QT and the only QT that should get here is QT hearts. OK losing to AA but that should have re-raised pre.  Villain could be doing this will lower sets.  Kx hearts could get here and bluff. QJ, QT, JT, 77, 55 could get here but those hands are more likely to call.  It seems hero is beating more hands than he is loosing to and getting 2:1.  I call here.  Don't know how the hero got away from this.